# SharePoint Online 2013 o365 . Keeping users inside Site Pages only

Tags: permissions, sharepoint-online, settings, office-365

Using Native SPO 2013 features is it possible to keep a group of users from opening anything but Site Pages?

I need these users to be able to write entries to a list, but I don't want them opening the following :

- Settings pages
- Ribbon Edit page settings
- Native Views for this or other Lists
- Restrict WebDAV, Office, SPD, oData access to the subsite for these users?

We are considering getting development help to do this, but wanted to check if there is a native feature first.

If there is no native feature to do this, please join me in asking MS for the feature through their suggestion site, the o365 Ticket system and your MS Account manager.

http://support.microsoft.com/common/survey.aspx?scid=sw;en-us;2222&altStyle=MFE&renderOption=OverrideDefault&showpage=1&fr=1&nofrbrand=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give users read-only access to your site pages in the site.  And then only grant them read access to the lists or libraries required to support viewing your pages (i.e. if you have an images library that you store images in for your pages).  The user will not see the Site Settings links, etc., if they don't have permissions to manage the site or site collection.

TechNet has a lot of information about user permissions and permission levels in SharePoint, I'd start here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc721640.aspx.  It is worth noting, that for this, there is virtually no different between Office 365 SharePoint and on-premise SharePoint.

Comment: Thank you. But what if I want users to  upload files to a library using a custon page but don't want them accessing the library directly via all-item views, WebDAV, office, SPD or odata?

Comment: Don't give them any permissions to the library.  Then, in your custom code on the page, do the operation as the system account so that the code can upload the file without giving access to the user.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spusertoken.systemaccount.aspx for getting the system account token.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sharepoint/ms469253.aspx for opening the site as the system account with that user token.

Comment: Thank You. Would you know if that custom code can be client side jQuery REST? I suspect not and we would have to deploy Sandbox WSP solutions right?

Answer (score 1):

- In continuation of John's mail, several activities can be limited
  also by creating your own custom permission level and then create a
  SharePoint Group linked to it (e.g for WebDav you could remove "Use
  Remote Interfaces" & "Use Client Integration Features" - but be aware
  that Ribbon actions will also get disabled accordingly). Try doing this before breaking security inheritance, as this could be the way to permisions-hell for administrators, and depending on the volume of data & users, could lead to performance issues.
- For Publishing sites there is also the lockdown feature - which
  locks access to library Forms (enable the ViewFormPagesLockdown
  feature -
  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/russmax/archive/2010/01/22/lockdown-mode-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx - hidden feature but enabled by default for Publishing),
  (though considering that you mention here "Site Pages" i believe you
  have a collaboration site - if you are only starting now with your
  project maybe you should consider that too as a way to control what
  controls are visible via Page Layouts).